# I can't understand how my If statements are being seen as true

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I'm doing a Rock, Paper, Scissors game and looking to add validation to the prompt method so that if users type any words typed that are not "rock", "paper" or "scissor" then we prompt again.

I can't seem to understand why the code below is not working and even when I type "rock" it prompts me again to enter.

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        let valid = false;
        let askPlayer = prompt("Rock, Paper or Scissor?");
        while(!valid) {
            if (askPlayer !== "rock" || askPlayer !== "paper" || askPlayer !== "scissor" || askPlayer !== "Rock" || askPlayer !== "Paper" || askPlayer !== "Scissor") {
                askPlayer = prompt("Enter again. You seem to have entered an invalid value");

            }
            else { valid = true; }
        }
        play(askPlayer, computerPlay());
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you might be getting your affirmatives v. negatives mixed up.  Your condition is saying "If the player provides a value that fails match any one of these, then ask again"

A more human-friendly condition to write would be:

```
var valid_responses = ["rock","paper","scissors"];
if (valid_responses.includes(askPlayer.toLowerCase())){
  valid = true;
} else {
  askPlayer = prompt("Enter again. You seem to have entered an invalid value");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you don't want this condition

```
askPlayer !== "rock" || askPlayer !== "paper" || askPlayer !== "scissor" || askPlayer !== "Rock" || askPlayer !== "Paper" || askPlayer !== "Scissor"
```

but this one

```
askPlayer !== "rock" && askPlayer !== "paper" && askPlayer !== "scissor" && askPlayer !== "Rock" && askPlayer !== "Paper" && askPlayer !== "Scissor"
```

Just change all of the `||` to `&&`

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your code is saying: 'if the input is not "rock" OR if the input is not "scissor" OR if the input is not "paper"... etc'.

So if you type in 'rock', you will be rejected because the input is not 'scissor' and not 'paper'.

You should be saying 'if the input is not "rock" AND if the input is not "scissor" AND if the input is not "paper"... etc'.

So change all your || to && :)

You could also try do askPlayer.toLowerCase() before checking its validity, so you don't have to repeat yourself with 'Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissor'.